# Помощь с функцией в Python

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь написать функцию, которая бы:

1. В случае если число кратно 7 говорила, что число кратно 7.
2. Если число не кратно 7, возвращала бы ближайшее к этому кратное 7, и писала "Ближайшее к вашему числу, кратное 7 - это .." . ну или как-то так.

У меня никак не получается сделать так, чтобы при нахождении ближайшего кратного числа, интерпретатор писал бы нужную фразу =\

Вот до чего я додумался пока что:

```
def cratn(n):
c = 0
if n % 7 == 0:
    print('Число', n, 'и так кратно 7ми')
if n % 7 == 0 and 0 < c < 7:
    print('Ближайшее к этому числу, число:', n)
else:
    c += 1
    return cratn(n+1)
```

Счётчик **с** я ввёл, чтобы отличать изначально введённое число, от ближайшего...по-другому, не могу никак реализовать =\

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```
def cratn(n):
  if n % 7 == 0:
    print('Число', n, 'и так кратно 7ми')
  else:
    left = (n // 7) * 7
    right = left + 7
    n = left if n - left < right - n else right
    print('Ближайшее к этому числу, число:', n)

cratn(14)
cratn(17)
cratn(18)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
def cratn(n, to=7):
    mod = n % to  # Находим остаток
    if mod == 0:  # Если число кратно 7
        print(f'Число {n} кратно {to}')
    else:
        nearest = n - mod  # Вычитаем остаток
        if mod > to / 2:  # Если остаток больше половины числа
            nearest += to  # Добавляем целое число, иначе nearest уже является ближайшим
        print(f'Ближайшее кратное {to} число к {n}: {nearest}')
```